# Python transforming ast through function decorators

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, python-decorators

I had an idea to transform all given functions that are tagged using a decorator similar to the below,

```
@transform_ast
def foo(x):
    return x
```

In `transform_ast`, I get the source, extract the ast, transform it, and then create a code object and function type from it again. It looks something like the below,

```
import ast
import inspect
import types

class Rewrite(ast.NodeTransformer):
    pass

def transform_ast(f):

    source = inspect.getsource(f)
    source = '\n'.join(source.splitlines()[1:]) # remove the decorator first line.
    print(source)

    old_code_obj = f.__code__
    old_ast = ast.parse(source)
    new_ast = Rewrite().visit(old_ast)
    new_code_obj = compile(new_ast, old_code_obj.co_filename, 'exec')
    new_f = types.FunctionType(new_code_obj, {})
    return new_f

@transform_ast
def foo(x):
    return x
```

However, it doesn't seem to work properly when I subsequently call foo(x).

For all practical purposes, we can assume my transform is just re-writing `return x` to `return x+1`. Ideally I would like everything to work as per-normal, including being able to step into the function with a debugger...

Calling `foo(10)`, would give the following error,

> TypeError: module() takes no arguments (1 given)

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
new_code_obj = compile(new_ast, old_code_obj.co_filename, 'exec')
```

The code compiled with `exec` mode is always treated as ***module-level code***, though, of course, it can contain function or class definitions, or any other valid Python).

To verify this, you can access [`co_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) attribute of the code object to get the ***name with which this code object was defined***.

```
>>> new_code_obj.co_name
<module>
```

ie, `new_code_obj` is a code object corresponding to a module. but where is the code object corresponding to the function `foo`. How can we access that?

It can access from the [`co_consts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) attribute of the code object which is a ***tuple of constants used in the bytecode***

```
>>> new_code_obj.co_consts
(<code object foo at 0x031C3DE0, file "c:/Users/test.py", line 1>, 'foo', None)
>>> new_code_obj.co_consts[0]
<code object foo at 0x031C3DE0, file "c:/Users/test.py", line 1>
```

To verify this code object is from the function `foo` you can use the [`co_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) attribute again.

```
>>> new_code_obj.co_consts[0].co_name
foo
```

So while creating the new `FunctionType` you should use the code object corresponding the function `foo` instead of the `module` code object.

So changing

```
new_f = types.FunctionType(new_code_obj, {})
```

to

```
new_f = types.FunctionType(new_code_obj.co_consts[0], f.__globals__)
# Here `f` is the function object passed to the `transform_ast`
```

will solve the problem.

Additional Refs: [Exploring Python Code Objects](https://late.am/post/2012/03/26/exploring-python-code-objects.html)

Comment: This won't work, try to use the decorator with `def foo(): return range(10)` for instance

Comment: Much better now ;) , +1 . One last thing, op should be careful when using several decorators as the way it's right now it's forcing the user to specify `@transform_ast` at the very top.